# How to Schedule Google Dataflow SQL jobs

Tags: google-cloud-dataflow, gcloud, scheduling

I am trying to explore the Dataflow sql feature. https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/docs/guides/sql/dataflow-sql-intro

I am able to submit and successfully execute the Dataflow job using SQL. Now I want to schedule this job every 15 mins.

I know for normal Dataflow job using JAVA sdk we can schedule the job using template.
I am unable to find any documentation on scheduling Dataflow SQL jobs.

Comment: If you want to run your Dataflow job every 15 min, I adivse you to write your Dataflow job using the the [Google BigQuery I/O connector](https://beam.apache.org/documentation/io/built-in/google-bigquery/) and schedule it using Cloud Scheduler as described in the [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/community/tutorials/schedule-dataflow-jobs-with-cloud-scheduler). Would that work for you?